# "Failed to build regex" when docker's image of "python:3.5-alpine" is built

Tags: python-3.x, docker

I am trying to build a docker image of python using the following dockerfile:
Could you help please to clarify.

```
FROM python:3.5-alpine
COPY sa /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt && \
   python3 -m textblob.download_corpora
EXPOSE 6000
ENTRYPOINT ["python3"]
CMD ["sentiment_analysis.py"]
```

And when I am trying to build i have got this error:

```
Building wheel for regex (setup.py): started
**Building wheel for regex (setup.py): finished with status 'error**'
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
command: /usr/local/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0]  = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-uf5dc85t/regex/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-uf5dc85t/regex/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-soszwszs
   cwd: /tmp/pip-install-uf5dc85t/regex/
 Complete output (17 lines):
 running bdist_wheel
 running build
 running build_py
 creating build
 creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5
 creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/regex
 copying regex_3/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/regex
 copying regex_3/regex.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/regex
 copying regex_3/_regex_core.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/regex
 copying regex_3/test_regex.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/regex
 running build_ext
 building 'regex._regex' extension
 creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5
 creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/regex_3
 gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-  prototypes -fPIC -I/usr/local/include/python3.5m -c regex_3/_regex.c -o  build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/regex_3/_regex.o
 unable to execute 'gcc': No such file or directory
 error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
 ----------------------------------------
**ERROR: Failed building wheel for regex**
Running setup.py clean for regex
Successfully built nltk MarkupSafe
Failed to build regex
```

Comment: gcc is not installed. Try to add `RUN apk add build-base` right after the FROM directive

Comment: Stefano, thanks a lot, now it works! _/\_ Have you a nice day!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After suggesting of [Stefano](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2037044/stefano) to add `RUN apk add build-base` right after the FROM directive - it works! Thanks, Stefano!